# SharePoint : Workflow > Send an Email > Customizations (CSS)

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, css, customization

I'm customizing the body of an email send by SharePoint's Workflow action "Send an Email".

Knowing that this action does not support what's inserted in the <"style"></"style"> tags and the only way is to do it inline within the target html tags, I'm currently facing the following issue: somewhere in my email's body text, I'm getting the value of a specific item's field (example: [%CurrentItem:Body%] which can contain images in between of the text. How can I apply the css in order to set this images' width and/or height?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Duarte

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can do this.

We recommend that you upload the appropriate image size directly in the column.